# How to set a build definition argument with the value of another argument

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm creating an argument that will be displayed in the Edit Build Definition window, then I need to get the value of this argument and set another one.

Name of the argument editable in the build definition window: FixedMajorVersion

Name of the argument that will receive FixedMajorVersion value: MSBuildArgument

I need to set MSBuildArgument as: "/p:FixedMajorVersion=" & FixedMajorVersion

However, the workflow editor on Visual Studio is not recognizing FixedMajorVersion.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Name of the argument that will receive FixedMajorVersion value:
>   MSBuildArgument

This just needs to be a variable. The argument is exposed, as with the Argument you wish the Build Engineer to supply, but MSBuild "argument" only needs to be internal.

set MSBuildArgument, in the variable declaration tab, default value to be

`"/p:FixedMajorVersion=" & FixedMajorVersion`